# Enhanced Auth Dialog Contains No Flow For LogOut?

Tags: facebook, dialog, logout, authentication, facebook-oauth

I am developing an app to add facebook logins in our company website. Because we already have our own registration/login code in place I am doing some integration work to make it all play nice. I really like the new Enhanced Auth Dialog as it lets me customize the dialog and doesnt need additional permission screens if all you need as email.

The problem I have is if person A logs into facebook.com and then leaves the computer. Person B navigates to my web site and want to login to my site via facebook. With the old permissions dialog from facebook it would show me who was currently logged in, and give a logout link, however, when I use the Enhanced Auth Dialog, it doesn't give Person B any way to log out. I think this is an oversight, because currently, if I bring a user to this dialog, they will see that it is someone else logged in, but if they cancel out of it, clicking login again brings them to the same place. I really don't want to send my users to facebook to logout!

Again, the old dialog works well, but it looks like it's being phased out. Is there any way around this? Also, how long do people have to upgrade their existing code before we are all forced to use the new dialog?

Thanks for any insight!

-Jeff